# How to set auto height in jquery colorbox?

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I am trying to open colorbox onclick. It is ok. But now i want to make the colorbox height set to auto (according to the height of the returned content height) and the scrollbar of the browser will be scrollable within the height of the colorbox content height. Here's my code

```
$('body').on('click', 'a.post', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.colorbox({
    width: "850px",
    height: "600px",
    iframe: true,
    href:this.href
  });
});
```

Any help? (thanks in advance)

Comment: I have tried this part of code from colorbox site, but no solution
                            $('a.post').colorbox.resize();

Comment: If you want auto height, why is it set to 600px?

Comment: @andyb -- I have tried to do this without the height option, but then it gets about 30 to 40 px height. That is why....

Comment: What kind of content do you put there? Is the content already there when you initialize the control?

Comment: no. that content will come from another page

Comment: There is an `initialHeight` option that might help. Can you create a demo with [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10066938/jquery-and-colorbox-how-to-automatically-set-the-height-and-width-of-an-iframe

Comment: @andyb Sorry, As i am displaying data in the lightbox from another page, creating jsFiddle will be difficult.

Comment: i am trying to do the modal window just like pinterest.com. @anydb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using Height via the `height()` method:

```
var objHeight=$(window).height()-100; // reduce 100, so that it will fit in the container

$.colorbox({
   width: "850px",
   height: objHeight,
   iframe: true,
   href: this.href
});
```

Comment: May be it will be helpful if i give any reference. actually i am trying to do the modal window just like pinterest.com. @anydb

Comment: your answer is helpful but not what i am trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Posting the answer for those who still might have this issue 
For auto height, this worked for me beautifully,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function openColorBox() {
        $.colorbox({ 
          href: "Something.aspx",
          onComplete: function () {
                $(this).colorbox.resize();
          }  
      });
    }
</script>
```